# IPN returns a different transaction id

Tags: transactions, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an error with Paypal: IPN gives me a different transaction id from the one shown in PayPal page (displayed PayPal you finish the payment, like in the attached image).

In my IPN file I take the transaction id from `$_POST['txn_id']`. Now I'm using the sandbox.

Is this my problem?

[image: transaction id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has a different transaction ID for the buyer and seller of a payment. If you compare the transaction ID in the IPN with the transaction ID with the seller's side, you'll find they are the same.

If a buyer calls in with his transaction ID and you want to automatically look up the matching PayPal transaction, use the GetTransactionDetails API.

Comment: I compare the id in the ipn (take from $_POST['txn_id']) with the transaction id in seller's page, but they aren't the same. Maybe I don't understand waht you write..